# No such file or directory upon running the program via g++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

So I downloaded [this project](https://github.com/wirekraken/Raspberry-Pi-NRF24/blob/master/receiver.cpp) off github but been having issues running the program via command line (have always used an IDE to do all the compilation, but i'm running on RPI so gotta rely on command line).

Following is the command that I ran with the output:

```
g++ -W -Wall -s receiver.cpp RF24/RF24.cpp
receiver.cpp:3:10: fatal error: RF24/RF24.h: No such file or directory
 #include <RF24/RF24.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Does anyone see what's potentially wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged C if you are writing C++?

Answer (score 0):

Try `g++ -I.` to tell gcc to look for include paths in current directory

The full commandline - going by above

```
g++ -I. -W -Wall -s receiver.cpp RF24/RF24.cpp
```

Comment: Does it compile all the source files in the current directory?

Comment: it will compile all the files you provide as arguments - in this case 2 files - receiver.cpp and RF24/RF24.cpp

Comment: Ah, so `-I` just tells the compiler to look for the 'specified' files in the current directory so you gotta still provide all the source files as arguments?

Comment: `-I` is specifically for `#include` paths - hopefully there actually is a file RF24/RF24.h - otherwise you have bigger problems!

Comment: the include in `RF24.cpp` is `#include "RF24.h", but `#include "RF24.cpp"` itself is located under `RF24/RF24.h` in relative to current directory. Upon running the command, I get a bunch of other undefined references in `RF24.cpp`

Comment: that's a different error from a different source file - receiver.cpp references RF24/RF24.h - RF24/RF24.cpp references RF24.h - you can add another `-I RF24` option to resolve the second error

Comment: It's unfortunate the project does not provide a makefile or cmake file - you may need to go through these errors one  by one to figure out all the relative paths to the header files - but every single one of these errors will be fixed by an appropriate `-I` option - also the project has a whole bunch of source files that are probably all needed to build an executable - so this is not an efficient way to go about it

Comment: wait doesn't `I.` include al the include paths anyways? why an additional `-I`? also are you saying it should be: `g++ -I. -I RF24 -W -Wall -s receiver.cpp RF24/RF24.cpp`?

Comment: yes - think of each `-I` as a prefix g++ will try with every `#include` - so an include path like RF24/RF24.h becomes `./RF24/RF24.h` but a path that's just `RF24.h` becomes `./RF24.h` which does not exist - but `-I RF24` lets gcc try `RF24/RF24.h` which works